# How to use IS NOT NULL in Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am new in Symfony framework And I want to use Query basis on Condition

which is using associative array and I want to use IS NOT NULL But it is not

working.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order');
$order = $repository->findBy(array('status' => $last_status,'new_coloumn_id'=>"IS NOT NULL"));
```

How to use **IS NOT NULL** in array.

Answer (score 4):

You should add custom function into your Order Repository file(class). Example;

```
public function getOrderStatus($last_status = NULL){
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('order')
        ->where('order.new_column_id IS NOT NULL')
        ->andWhere('status = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', $last_status);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And you can use it;

```
$order = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->getOrderStatus($last_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your repository class:

```
public function findOrder($last_status){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('order');

        return $qb->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('order.new_column_id'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('order.status',':last_status'))
            ->setParameter('last_status',$last_status)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();//getArrayResult,getResult()

    }
```

hope it helps...